# Swagger UI express shows blank page when host in server

Tags: express, swagger-ui, autogen

I have generated the swagger JSON file below using "swagger-autogen"

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "title": "api-impact",
    "description": "Documentation automatically generated by the <b>swagger-autogen</b> module."
  },
  "host": "localhost:3000",
  "basePath": "/v1",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "CRUD",
      "description": "Endpoints classic CRUD"
    },
    {
      "name": "Search",
      "description": "Different search strategy to get equipements"
    },
    {
      "name": "Utils",
      "description": "Utils endpoints"
    }
  ],
  "schemes": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/v1/equipement/CRUD/": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "CRUD"
        ],
        "description": "create an equipement",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true,
            "in": "query"
          },
          {
            "name": "equipement",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "description": "equipement",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/CRUD/{id}": {
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "CRUD"
        ],
        "description": "modify the equipement by the id",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "equipement",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "description": "equipement",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "CRUD"
        ],
        "description": "delete an equipement by its id",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      },
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "CRUD"
        ],
        "description": "Get the equipement by the id",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Equipement with the specified id ",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/search/all": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Search"
        ],
        "description": "Get all equipement in the database",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Array of all the equipements",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/search/mongo_query": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Search"
        ],
        "description": "Access equipements with a mongoDB find query passed in body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "obj",
            "in": "body",
            "required": true,
            "description": "Mongo Query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {}
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Array of the equipements returned by the mongo query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/search/text": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Search"
        ],
        "description": "Search equipement via a text query on name and brand",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "n",
            "description": "Number of results wanted",
            "required": false,
            "type": "number",
            "in": "query"
          },
          {
            "name": "searchString",
            "description": "search text query",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "in": "query"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Array of the equipements returned by the text query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/search/query_param": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Search"
        ],
        "description": "Access equipements by parameters",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "type",
            "type": "string",
            "in": "query"
          },
          {
            "name": "brand",
            "type": "string",
            "in": "query"
          },
          {
            "name": "segmentation",
            "in": "query",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Array of the equipements returned by the parameter query",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Equipement"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/utils/getAllBrands": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Utils"
        ],
        "description": "Return all the existing brands",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Array of the brand names",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "example": [
                "string"
              ],
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/utils/getAllTypes": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Utils"
        ],
        "description": "Return all the existing type of equipement",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "example": [
                "string"
              ],
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            },
            "description": "Array of the equipements type"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/v1/equipement/utils/getAllSegmentation": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Utils"
        ],
        "description": "Return all the existing segmentation of equipement",
        "parameters": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "example": [
                "string"
              ],
              "items": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "xml": {
                "name": "main"
              }
            },
            "description": "Array of the equipements segmentation"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Equipement": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "Dell Vostro"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "Ordinateur"
        },
        "brand": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "Dell"
        },
        "segementation": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "Portable"
        },
        "descritpion": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": " ... "
        },
        "date_modify": {
          "type": "string",
          "example": "2012-04-23T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "impact_cc": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "cc"
            },
            "unit": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "Kg CO2 eq."
            },
            "cradle_to_gate_impact": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 30
            },
            "gate_to_grave_impact": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 40
            },
            "transport_impact": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 45
            },
            "use_impact": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 32
            },
            "eof_impact": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 12
            },
            "margin_error": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 12
            },
            "year_usage": {
              "type": "number",
              "example": 4
            },
            "methodology": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "test"
            },
            "use_methodology": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "none"
            },
            "source": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "dede"
            },
            "impact_factor": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "55"
            },
            "date_publication": {
              "type": "string",
              "example": "2012-04-23T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When i use "swagger-ui-express" to display it, it works on my localhost. But when installed on a server, the swagger page is blank (even when curled from the server itself).

```js
app.use('/doc', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerFile));
```

Blank page :

```html
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Swagger UI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" >
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" /><link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  
  <style>
    html
    {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after
    {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
      margin:0;
      background: #fafafa;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0">
  <defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="unlocked">
      <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V6h2v-.801C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8z"></path>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="locked">
      <path d="M15.8 8H14V5.6C14 2.703 12.665 1 10 1 7.334 1 6 2.703 6 5.6V8H4c-.553 0-1 .646-1 1.199V17c0 .549.428 1.139.951 1.307l1.197.387C5.672 18.861 6.55 19 7.1 19h5.8c.549 0 1.428-.139 1.951-.307l1.196-.387c.524-.167.953-.757.953-1.306V9.199C17 8.646 16.352 8 15.8 8zM12 8H8V5.199C8 3.754 8.797 3 10 3c1.203 0 2 .754 2 2.199V8z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="close">
      <path d="M14.348 14.849c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0L10 11.819l-2.651 3.029c-.469.469-1.229.469-1.697 0-.469-.469-.469-1.229 0-1.697l2.758-3.15-2.759-3.152c-.469-.469-.469-1.228 0-1.697.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0L10 8.183l2.651-3.031c.469-.469 1.228-.469 1.697 0 .469.469.469 1.229 0 1.697l-2.758 3.152 2.758 3.15c.469.469.469 1.229 0 1.698z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow">
      <path d="M13.25 10L6.109 2.58c-.268-.27-.268-.707 0-.979.268-.27.701-.27.969 0l7.83 7.908c.268.271.268.709 0 .979l-7.83 7.908c-.268.271-.701.27-.969 0-.268-.269-.268-.707 0-.979L13.25 10z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 20 20" id="large-arrow-down">
      <path d="M17.418 6.109c.272-.268.709-.268.979 0s.271.701 0 .969l-7.908 7.83c-.27.268-.707.268-.979 0l-7.908-7.83c-.27-.268-.27-.701 0-.969.271-.268.709-.268.979 0L10 13.25l7.418-7.141z"/>
    </symbol>


    <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="jump-to">
      <path d="M19 7v4H5.83l3.58-3.59L8 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41L5.83 13H21V7z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="expand">
      <path d="M10 18h4v-2h-4v2zM3 6v2h18V6H3zm3 7h12v-2H6v2z"/>
    </symbol>

  </defs>
</svg>

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
<script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>
<script src="./swagger-ui-init.js"> </script>

<style>
  .swagger-ui .topbar .download-url-wrapper { display: none } undefined
</style>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance if you have some clues how to resolve this